# How to unzip only the first few lines of a zip archive?

Tags: zip, extract, cat, tail

I have a zipped text file `a.zip` I want to read the first 10 lines of it. Is it possible to do that without unzipping the whole file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This simple pipe-script works for me:

```
zcat a.zip | head -n 10
```

Here:

- `zcat a.zip` - unpacks zip-archive and sends its contents to standard output
- `|` pipes `zcat` output to `head` input
- `head -n 10` - shows first 10 lines from its standard input

Comment: this unzips the whole file.

Comment: @yukashima I'd guess it depends on the size of `a.zip`. When `head` terminates (after printing 10 lines) the `zcat` (which is `gzip -dc` behind the scenes) should receive a SIGPIPE and stop unzipping.

Comment: @yukashimahuksay How do you know it unzips the whole file? I think all zip files keep the file list at the end of the archive, maybe it's just reading the whole file but not actually unzipping it

Comment: I can confirm by example that it does not unzip the whole file as intended. `zcat verybigfile.zip | head -10` prints the first 10 lines _immediately_. A full unzip would take ca. 10 minutes.